# So I created a params hash, assigned it values, trying to extract a value.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, parameters

```
person1 = Person.new
person1.first = "Tim"
person1.last = "Happy"

person2 = Person.new
person2.first = "Zack"
person2.last = "Sad"

person3 = Person.new
person3.first = "Al"
person3.last = "Angry"

params = {:father => person1, :mother => person2, :child => person3} #params hash
puts params[:father][:first]
```

I'm trying to get it to print just Tim. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Person` appears to be a class (not the same as a `Hash`), so it can't be accessed in that way unless the class has explicitly defined an `[]` accessor (as [`ActiveRecord::Base` does](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000410), for example). What you want is:

```
puts params[:father].first
```

This can admittedly be confusing coming from a language like, e.g., JavaScript, where the two notations are interchangeable.

Comment: @RyanBigg: What makes you think it's an ActiveRecord object? I see no indications of that anywhere; furthermore, the fact the OP has run into this problem in the first place suggests to me the opposite.